# what is the meaning of ',\n' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL and in my book I was reading over the `concat` page and on the `concat_WS` query I couldn't figure out what `',\n'` means. Here it is.

```
create table if not exists hotels (
    name varchar(25) primary key,
    street varchar(25),
    city varchar(25),
    state varchar(25),
    zip int);

insert into hotels (name, street, city, state, zip) 
            values ('Las Vegas Hilton', '3000 Paradise Road', 
                    'Las Vegas', 'Nevada', 89109);  

select concat(name, ', ', state) from hotels;

select concat_ws('\n', name, street, city, state, zip) from hotels;
```

Comment: `\n` =  an enter character. As simple as that.

Comment: To be more precise, it is a line break character. :P